# How to perform forward fill logic in PANDAS based on 'ent_id' if it does not exist for successive date then perform forward fill?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

let's say i have a data frame as

```
effective_date,ent_id,val
2020-02-03,101,aa
2020-02-03,102,ab
2020-02-03,103,ac
2020-02-03,105,ad

2020-02-04,107,ba
2020-02-04,103,bd
2020-02-04,105,bv
2020-02-04,106,bs
2020-02-04,109,be
2020-02-04,102,bn

2020-02-05,117,ca
2020-02-05,113,cd
2020-02-05,115,cv
2020-02-05,106,cs
2020-02-05,109,ce
2020-02-05,102,cn
```

and the output would be like i.e. if the ent_id does not exist for successive date the forward fill it
e.g. as on effective_date '2020-02-04' we don't have ent_id as 101 hence it is fill forwarded to next date i.e. 2020-02-04,101,aa and similarly for other date as well

```
effective_date,ent_id,val
2020-02-03,101,aa
2020-02-03,102,ab
2020-02-03,103,ac
2020-02-03,105,ad

2020-02-04,101,aa
2020-02-04,107,ba
2020-02-04,103,bd
2020-02-04,105,bv
2020-02-04,106,bs
2020-02-04,109,be
2020-02-04,102,bn

2020-02-05,101,aa
2020-02-05,107,ba
2020-02-05,103,bd
2020-02-05,105,bv
2020-02-05,117,ca
2020-02-05,113,cd
2020-02-05,115,cv
2020-02-05,106,cs
2020-02-05,109,ce
2020-02-05,102,cn
```

my effort

```
df['effective_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['effective_date'])

df1 = (df.set_index(['effective_date',df.groupby('effective_date').cumcount()])
         .unstack()
         .ffill()
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index())
```

but it is no providing the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just pivot, ffill, then unstack:

```
(df.pivot(index='effective_date', columns='ent_id')
   .ffill().stack().reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   effective_date  ent_id val
0      2020-02-03     101  aa
1      2020-02-03     102  ab
2      2020-02-03     103  ac
3      2020-02-03     105  ad
4      2020-02-04     101  aa
5      2020-02-04     102  bn
6      2020-02-04     103  bd
7      2020-02-04     105  bv
8      2020-02-04     106  bs
9      2020-02-04     107  ba
10     2020-02-04     109  be
11     2020-02-05     101  aa
12     2020-02-05     102  cn
13     2020-02-05     103  bd
14     2020-02-05     105  bv
15     2020-02-05     106  cs
16     2020-02-05     107  ba
17     2020-02-05     109  ce
18     2020-02-05     113  cd
19     2020-02-05     115  cv
20     2020-02-05     117  ca
```